# If user input is not part of string values asked, default output

Tags: python, input, calculator

Here is a code I made a while ago, I want to make it so that by default it calls the add function, so if I just input enter (or anything) it will ask me what two numbers I wish to add.
I have tried putting,

```
else:
num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))
print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
```

but that is not working, any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the entire code below

```
import math as m
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

def power(x, y):
    return x ** y

def nroot(x, y):
    return x ** (1/y)

def sin(D):
    R = D / 180 * m.pi
    return(m.sin(R))
def cos(D):
    R = D / 180 * m.pi
    return(m.cos(R))

print("Select Operation.")
print("1. Add")
print("2. Subtract")
print("3. Multiply")
print("4. Divide")
print("5. Exponent")
print("6. sin(Degrees)")
print("7. cos(Degrees)")

while True:
    # Take input from user
    choice = input("Enter Choice[1-7]: ")

    #check if choice is one of the four
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))

    if choice == '1':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '2':
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '3':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '5':
        print(num1, "^", num2, "=", power(num1, num2))

    if choice in('6','7'):
        angle = float(input('Enter Angle in degrees: '))

    if choice =='6':
        print('sin(',angle,') = ',sin(angle))
    elif choice =='7':
        print('cos(',angle,') = ',cos(angle))
  
    break
```

Comment: **but that is not working** what does working mean here? Do you want `add` to be called by default if the choice is not inside `('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')`? You also have  `('6','7')` so **do you want to check if they are also not `'6'` or `'7'`**. Please be more clear, what does **by default** mean? **if I just input enter (or anything)**, so you always want `add` to be called? You said anything. Then why even write the others?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me-

```
import math as m
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

def power(x, y):
    return x ** y

def nroot(x, y):
    return x ** (1/y)

def sin(D):
    R = D / 180 * m.pi
    return(m.sin(R))
def cos(D):
    R = D / 180 * m.pi
    return(m.cos(R))

print("Select Operation.")
print("1. Add")
print("2. Subtract")
print("3. Multiply")
print("4. Divide")
print("5. Exponent")
print("6. sin(Degrees)")
print("7. cos(Degrees)")

while True:
    # Take input from user
    choice = input("Enter Choice[1-7]: ")

    #check if choice is one of the four
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))
    # Update:
    else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter First Number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number: "))
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

    if choice == '1':
        print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '2':
        print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '3':
        print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '4':
        print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
    elif choice == '5':
        print(num1, "^", num2, "=", power(num1, num2))

    if choice in('6','7'):
        angle = float(input('Enter Angle in degrees: '))

    if choice =='6':
        print('sin(',angle,') = ',sin(angle))
    elif choice =='7':
        print('cos(',angle,') = ',cos(angle))
  
    break
```

Comment: What about choices `6` and `7`? Not only does `choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')` have to fail but also `choice in('6','7')` has to do as well in order to default to addition.

Comment: This is not working, possibly because I am using  Jupyter - notebooks?

Comment: @Countour-Integral I did not change the logic, just answered the question.

Comment: @MathandPhysicsFun This should not happen, can you try using some other compiler just to be sure?

Comment: @Shradha All python implementations are interpreted, there is no "compiler".

Comment: Hey easy buddy, that's just a generic term.